# Looping through a range row by row

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA I would like to select a specific range such as B7:J7, do something (I already have this working) then select the same columns in the next row, B8:J8 and do the same operation, then cycle to the next row, etc through a set range of rows.  The complete range would be something like B7:J40.  It seems easy but I haven't gotten anywhere.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rowIndex as Long

for rowIndex = 7 to 40   
    Sheet1.Range("B" & rowIndex & ":J" & rowIndex)
next col
```

this would give you
B7:J7
B8:J8
B9:J9
...
B40:J40

Comment: Naming conventions has to be programmer friendly. You seem to loop the rows, but with the name as `col`. I would suggest you to change it to `row`

Comment: Yes, you are correct as col is rather referring to rows and not columns as might be implied by the naming used

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code/self explanatory example. Modify it per your needs.

```
Sub loops()
Dim rownum As Long
'looping rows 7 to 40
For rownum = 7 To 40
    'Assuming you want to sum the range and put the output in K7, K8, K9 and so on...
    Range("K" & rownum) = WorksheetFunction.sum(Range("B" & rownum & ":j" & rownum))
Next rownum
End Sub
```